# How do you do simple arithmetic options in bash without getting a syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm getting syntax errors when trying to do some simple calculations in a bash shell script.  Obviously I'm doing it wrong but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
diffSec=`expr $diff % 60`              # works fine
diffMin=`expr $diff / 60 % 60`         # works fine
diffHr=`expr $diff / (60 * 60)`        # giving me problems due to the parens
testerme=`expr $diff / 3600`           # works fine but will use only as a work around
diffDay=`expr $diff / (60 * 60 * 24)`  # problems again
```

This is the syntax error I get:

```
./testscript.sh: command substitution: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./testscript.sh: command substitution: line 27: `expr $diff / (60 * 60)'
./testscript.sh: command substitution: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./testscript.sh: command substitution: line 29: `expr $diff / (60 * 60 * 24)'
```

How do i execute things within parenthesis such that I don't get a syntax error?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `man expr`: _" Beware  that many operators need to be escaped or quoted for shells."_ => `expr $diff / \(60 \* 60 \* 24 \)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **$(( ))**

```
diffSec=$(( $diff % 60 ))              # works fine
diffMin=$(( $diff / 60 % 60 ))        # works fine
diffHr=$(( $diff / (60 * 60) ))       # giving me problems due to the parens
testerme=$(( $diff / 3600 ))          # works fine but will use only as a work around
diffDay=$(( $diff / (60 * 60 * 24) )) # problems again
```

Answer (score 1):

```
diff=1234567
diffSec=$(( $diff % 60))         
diffMin=$(( $diff / 60 % 60))    
diffHr=$(( $diff / (60 * 60))) 
testerme=$(( $diff / 3600)) 
diffDay=$(( $diff / (60 * 60 * 24)))
echo $diffDay days $diffHr hours $diffMin min $diffSec sec
```

Output:

```
14 days 342 hours 56 min 7 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses and other symbols must be escaped so that the shell doesn't interpret them.
Also you need spaces around the parens.

```
A=`expr 100000 / \( 60 \* 60 \)`
```

Comment: should really use the $() syntax

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your parentheses are being interpreted as if part of globs, but the patterns don't seem to be terminated (since there's a space in between).[1] These will need to be escaped; the `*` will also require escaping to avoid being used as a glob.

Second, `expr` doesn't actually accept parentheses as *part* of one of the arguments; they need to be separate arguments.

As such, you probably want

```
diffHr=`expr $diff / \ (60 \* 60 \)`
```

Likewise,

```
diffHr=`expr $diff / \ (60 \* 60 \* 24 \)`
```

That said, `bash` provides the `$(( ))` construct as well, and it's probably a better idea to use that.

```
diffHr=$(( $diff/(60*60) ))
diffDay=$(( $diff/(60*60*24) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a completely different solution, have you ever thought about using the command line program `dc` (stands for desk calculator)?

It is a stack based calculator (also known as reverse polish)

```
diffSec=`echo '$diff 60 %p' | dc`
diffMin=`echo '$diff 60 60 /%p' | dc`
diffHr=`echo '$diff 60 60 */p' | dc`
diffDay=`echo '$diff 60 60 24 **/p' | dc`
```